# Como instalar Kivy python3 en Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy

¿Alguien sabe como instalar Kivy Python 3.10 en Ubuntu 22.04?
Intento correr:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.3.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Y me dice:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!